# You can not use prime number factorization theorem. If a|n and b|n and gcd(a,b)=1, then show ab|n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having a hard time proving it without using prime number factorization. I separated gcd(a,b)= 1 go an+bm=1, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: To prevent confusion, change names. There are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by=1$. It follows that $anx+bny=n$. Because $b$ divides $n$, it divides $nx$, so $ab$ divides $anx$. Continue.

Answer (score 2):

Since $a\:|\:n$, by definition we have $n=a\cdot k_{1}$ for an integer $k_{1}$. Similarly for b, we get $n=b\cdot k_{2}$.

Hence $a\cdot k_{1}=b\cdot k_{2}$ and since $(a,b)=1$, we have that $a$ divides $k_{2}$.

Hence $k_{2}=a\cdot k_{3}$.

Then $n=b\cdot k_{2}=b(a\cdot k_{3})=(ab)\cdot k_{3}$.

And so $ab\:|\:n$.